# I wanted to get data from my django mobels but it's shown error context must be a dict rather than QuerySet

Tags: django, django-models

I tried to pull the data from my models but It's return 
"{'data': <QuerySet [<WareHousePlan:  Part ID : 1 Part No : 71398-KK010-00 PartName : HOLDER RR
Depart Time : 2020-09-18 22:27:00  Status : True>]>}"

which cause TypeError

What should I do ?

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def Home(request):
    return render(request,'Warehouse/HomePage.html')

from .models import WareHousePlan

def ShowSchedule(request):
    data = WareHousePlan.objects.all()
    context = {"data": data}
    return render(request,'Warehouse/Showschedule.html',data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the `data` which is a `QuerySet` instead of `context` which is a dictionary that maps the `'data'` to this queryset. You thus should pass the `context`:

```
def ShowSchedule(request):
    data = WareHousePlan.objects.all()
    context = { 'data': data }
    return render(request, 'Warehouse/Showschedule.html', context)
```